# how can i write a jsp page that include save , submit, view buttons?

Tags: html, jsp

i want write a jsp page which must have 3 buttons like $save$ to save the      process we have done, to delete, to view what we have done.

```
i tried as :
<form action="go_save" method="post"> // how to go_view.jsp, go_delete.jsp
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">


code :
      <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
     <body>
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>
     <form action="go.jsp" method="post" >
         name<input type="text" name="name">
         age<input type="text" name="age">
         <input type="button" value="Save" name="Save" 
         onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'go_save.jsp'; return true;" />
          <input type="button" value="view" name="view" 
          onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'go_view.jsp'; return true;" />
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

but here the page is not redirecting to the given pages like go_view, go_save.
i want to catch these values name, age in go_view, go_save . but how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this...have an onclick event

```
<button type="button" onclick="location = 'go_save.jsp'">Save</button>
<button type="button" onclick="location = 'go_view.jsp'">Save</button>
```

remove the "action="go_save""

Comment: you mean i should write                                                                    <input type="button" value="Save" name="delete" 
     onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'go_delete.jsp'; return    true;" />                                                                      <input type="button" value="view" name="view"                  
 onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'go_view.jsp'; return true;" />

Answer (score 0):

You should do this job in a controller, probably a Servlet rather than the JSP.

Create a Servlet(say, `RedirectServlet` - you can naem), and in `doPost` method, redirect to the relevant JSP page, based on what button was clicked. You can give each button some name for this task.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if (request.getParameter("GoSave") != null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/go_save.jsp").forward(request, response);

    } else if (request.getParameter("GoDelete") != null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/go_delete.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }  else if (request.getParameter("GoView") != null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/go_view.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Now, from your form, instead of redirecting to a jsp page, redirect to this servlet:

```
<form action="redirectServlet" method="post"> 
   name<input type="text" name="name">
   age<input type="text" name="age">

   <input type="submit" name="GoView" value="SUBMIT">
   <input type="submit" name="GoDelete" value="SUBMIT">
   <input type="submit" name="GoSave" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Now, you can get the value of `name` and `age` is respective JSP page, where the servlets redirected the request to, using `request.getParameter("name")`.

Or you can also use some pattern like - [MVC's Front Controller Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297)